# DataTable IndexOverFlow Exception

Tags: c#, datatable

I wrote this bit of code to access a DataTable, however it throws the OutOfBounds Exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  //Computing Values of v1, v2
  v_1 = v_1 + RGen(0, 2) * (x1_l - x1_best) + RGen(0, 2) * (x1_best - (double)table.Rows[0].ItemArray[i]);
  v_2 = v_2 + RGen(0, 2) * (x2_l - x2_best) + RGen(0, 2) * (x2_best - (double)table.Rows[1].ItemArray[i]);

  x1.Add(Relax((double)table.Rows[0].ItemArray[i] + v_1));
  x2.Add(Relax((double)table.Rows[1].ItemArray[i] + v_2));
}
```

The DataTable is surely populated. What have I Missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is an index of *row*, but you are using it to access `ItemsArray` (which are cells). You should use columns instead

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{
   //...
}
```